# Windows Powershell - 'MaximumAllowed' parameter in Win32_Share Create method

Tags: windows, powershell

Any idea what the 'MaximumAllowed' parameter should be set to in order to have the "Maximum allowed" radio button ticked on the shared folder properties in Windows? I know it would be the same as having say 100 concurrent users but i'm curious to know whether this is achievable.
thanks in advance.
Tom

uint32 Create(
  [in]  string Path,
  [in]  string Name,
  [in]  uint32 Type,
  [in]  uint32 MaximumAllowed,
  [in]  string Description,
  [in]  string Password,
  [in]  Win32_SecurityDescriptor Access
);

Comment: Windows share information is stored in the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares section of the registry. For shares having the "Maximum Allowed" option checked I see a value of 4294967295 so you might try that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Windows SDK 6.1, the SHARE_INFO_2 structure which is defined in the Lmshare.h header file:

```
shi2_max_uses 

Specifies a DWORD value that indicates the maximum number of concurrent connections
that the shared resource can accommodate. The number of connections is unlimited if
the value specified in this member is –1.
```

Comment: much appreciate your quick turnaround! Tom

Comment: Value 4294967295 worked for me. "-1" did not though. thanks again tchester. Tom